# Collect data, but skip non-zero referenced-data

Tags: list, prolog

i have the following

```
fnf([],[],[]).
fnf([RH|RT],[CH|CT],[[RH,CH]|Res]) :- get(RH,CH,V), V == 0, fnf(RT,CT,Res).
```

i'm trying to collect only elements of Cs and Rs for which the V is zero.
The code above does that but fails when it hits non-zero value.
I want to just skip them, instead of failing the whole goal.

---

this sort of works

```
fnf([RH|RT],[CH|CT],[[RH,CH]|Res]) :- get(RH,CH,V), ( V == 0 -> fnf(RT,CT,Res);true).
```

still _2044 !! should not be there

```
F = [[1, 1], [2, 2]|_2044].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test only once (`get/3` + condition) and then keep the item or skip it and continue recursion you can use an if-then-else construct like so:

```
fnf([], [], []).
fnf([RH|RT], [CH|CT], Res) :-
    get(RH, CH, V),
    (   V==0                  % test
    ->  Res=[[RH, CH]|Res1]   % condition met, keep item
    ;   Res=Res1              % condition not met, skip item
    ),
    fnf(RT, CT, Res1).
```

Also note the call to `get/3` may backtrack if it leaves choicepoints.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a case for 0 and a case for non-zero:

```
fnf([],[],[]).

fnf([RH|RT],[CH|CT],[[RH,CH]|Res]) :- 
    get(RH,CH,0),
    fnf(RT,CT,Res).

fnf([_|RT],[_|CT],Res) :- 
    get(RH,CH,V),
    dif(V, 0),
    fnf(RT,CT,Res).
```

or

```
pairs_keys_values(Pairs, Rs, Cs),
findall([RH,CH], (member(RH-CH, Pairs), get(RH, CH, 0)), F).
```